# Type 'string' is not assignable to type

Tags: typescript

```
const opts = {
    provider: 'SG',
    logLevel: 'info', // <--- here is what the error is referring to
    providerBaseUrl:
    ...
```

Error:

```
test/contract/api.provider.spec.ts:81:47 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ provider: string; logLevel: string; providerBaseUrl: string; stateHandlers: { 'Has list of stations': () => Promise<string>; 'Has list of terminals': () => Promise<string>; 'Has list of centerlines': () => Promise<...>; }; ... 5 more ...; providerVersion: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'VerifierOptions'.
  Types of property 'logLevel' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"error" | "trace" | "debug" | "info" | "warn" | "fatal" | undefined'.

81             const output = await new Verifier(opts).verifyProvider();
                                                 ~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

Why is TypeScript complaining. I'm obviously setting a string value for that property.

Comment: What's the interface/type of `VerifierOptions`?

Comment: Because the `logLevel` in a `VerifierOptions` isn't just `string`, it's a [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types).

Comment: @r3dst0rm Why would that matter? It's telling me that the type of the property is incompatible?

Comment: Well, I did think in the wrong direction at first. As @jonrsharpe already mentioned. It's because your `opts` object has `logLevel` set to: type `string`. But your `VerifierOptions` do have a `string literal type` which does not match. Fixable by: `const opts: VerifierOptions = { ... }`

Comment: You can have a look at my sketch here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGrWDY0DyAHMYAexAGdkBvZAGyIHMAZCANwmoC5kAiUGIr5AB9u0KESgCAvgG4AsACgFCEqTDIAHsgC8lBchr0mrDsgDkvIqYA0CyQoUwAriASESyMEQBCEAMJxqaggAEwAKIgJiMk50KExsKHw3MgBKXXl9KAgwRygQDyhHCDl5O0V5Tx9-QJDQ9RSSpRU1AE8YjCxcSJVtdP1aRhY2Th4QPi5bewrvPwCgsJaGoA

Comment: @r3dst0rm Thanks man. It was indeed because of the string literal.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You were correct dude!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments under the question suggested it was because of `string` vs string literal.

There are two/three ways to solve this:

```
// Type safe approach
const opts: VerifierOptions = {
    provider: 'SG',
    logLevel: 'info',
```

Or:

```
// Not type safe approach
const opts = {
    provider: 'SG',
    logLevel: 'info' as VerifierOptions['logLevel'],
```

And if you need to use a variable:

```
// Not type safe approach
const opts = {
    provider: 'SG',
    logLevel: someVar as VerifierOptions['logLevel'],
```

Comment: as typescript said: " Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"error" | "trace" | "debug" | "info" | "warn" | "fatal" | undefined'."... message is not misleading. you just didnt understand that error

Comment: Just to complete the above. Using `someVar as VerifierOptions['logLevel']` does turn off the type check here. Means, setting something like: `logLevel: "thisWillBreakMuhahahaha" as VerifierOptions['logLevel']` would compile correctly but could result in a runtime error under circumstances. Therefore the first approach is 100% type-safe (and would complain about issues at compile time) whereas the latter one is not.

Comment: @JurajKocan So why didn't the compiler know the naming of type: `'"error" | "trace" | "debug" | "info" | "warn" | "fatal" | undefined'.` ?

Comment: @r3dst0rm I am using the third approach in my application due to the value coming in from an environmental variable so it cannot be a string literal in my case.

Comment: If it's possible in your case, you can change the type of `logLevel` to an enum (as it seems VerifierOptions are under your control). Which would allow you to parse the string, and therefore keep your typesafety. As sketched here: https://codesandbox.io/s/zx1c0

Comment: @KarlMorrison compiler didn't know that you want to use string literal as typeof VerifierOptions['logLevel']. in your case it was just string.